# C++ GPL Standard header

Tags: gpl, license

I'm new to C/C++.

When I import , the license text looks as follows:

```
// Copyright (C) 1997-2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
// permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
// 3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
// a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
// see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively. If not, see
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/** @file include/cstdlib
 *  This is a Standard C++ Library file.  You should @c \#include this file
 *  in your programs, rather than any of the @a *.h implementation files.
 *
 *  This is the C++ version of the Standard C Library header @c stdlib.h,
 *  and its contents are (mostly) the same as that header, but are all
 *  contained in the namespace @c std (except for names which are defined
 *  as macros in C).
 */

//
// ISO C++ 14882: 20.4.6  C library
///
```

This is the GPLv3 license. This applies to all libraries, e. g. , too. The files lie in `/usr/include/c++/9`. Do I understand it correctly, that if I use any of the standard libs, my program needs to be GPL, too? How is this done in practice, when I dont want it to be GPL? Thanks

I have also googled and have done some research, but its still unclear to me.

Comment: Have you read the "additional permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version 3.1", and if so, what is not clear about those additional permissions?